# Reading in voice transcripts into R

Tags: r, txt

I have a number of `.txt` files that contain voice-to-text transcripts. These are just text files with no columns, delimiters etc.

The text files look similar to this:

```
 TextFile1 <- "Hello, I am looking for information on a product you have in store."
 TextFile2 <- "Hi, I want to complain about a staff member in your London store."
 TextFile3 <- "Can you please give me information regarding your Christmas campaign?"
```

I am trying to read them into R so that I can join the transcript to the ID that it is associated with, which is in a separate `.csv` file.

The name of the `.txt` file is also the `ID`.

I am struggling to find a way to insert this data as it is just text and most functions I can find are for `.txt` files that have columns etc.

My end goal here is to have something that looks like the below:

```
 ID    Text
  1    "Hello, I am looking for information on a product you have in store."
  2    "Hi, I want to complain about a staff member in your London store."
  3    "Can you please give me information regarding your Christmas campaign?"
```

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible (at least, not for me) to give an answer without relavant sample data. Please create some and edit it into your question.

Comment: a first start: create a list of files to read, using `list.files()`, then use `lapply` to loop over this list, reading the files using `data.table::fread()` with the `sep=""` and `header = FALSE` arguments. Finally, bind the output together using `data.table::rbindlist()`. SO: `library(data.table); rbindlist(lapply(list.files(...), fread, sep = "", header = FALSE, ...), ...)`, where `...` are function's arguments. See the helpfiles of the functions to find out more.

Comment: @Wimpel you should post this as an answer because, given the context of the OP, it sounds like the correct answer. Also suggest providing a solution without dependency on `data.table`.